# How to edit 'iTunes Movie' to be visible on iPhone's iMovie

Tags: iphone, video, imovie

Videos that I've shot with my iPhone and are in my videos folder show up just fine on iMovie for iPhone as "addable media".

BUT I recently had a professionally designed short "intro" video for my videos that I want to use as a lead-in to my iMovie for iPhone projects. And that intro video does NOT show up my videos folder on iPhone when I transfer it into my iPhone.

Instead, that intro video seems to be somehow classified as a "movie" in iTunes on the iPhone, which can't be imported into iMovie. Any fixes here? A way to somehow get that intro video into the videos folder on the iPhone, or be able to add media from my iTunes movie folder into iMovie for iPhone?

Comment: You title makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will need to use iTunes to sync the intro video over to your iPhone.

1. Connect your iPhone to iTunes and select it.
2. Click the "Apps" tab, and scroll down to "**File Sharing**".
3. Select iMovie from the list.
4. Select "*Add...*" from the lower right corner.
5. Browse your documents to find the intro video and open it.
6. Sync it over to your iPhone.
7. iMovie should recognize is as soon as the sync is completed and you should be able to use it normally.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this process certainly is another way to add the video to the phone, iMovie doesn't recognize it - whether the file is added as .m4v or as .mov.

Comment: When I click "add media" in iMovie for iPhone it only shows videos I have shot with my iPhone and not videos added via iTunes.

Comment: Wow. I totally missed the point, somehow, in your question. The method I gave works using the Download arrow in iMovie. This may be theoretically possible by opening your intro and then duplicating and adding to it every time - certainly far from ideal, though. Can you email the intro video to yourself, and then tap and hold to save it to your iPhone? This has worked for me, but obviously the intro must be small enough to email.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using a different approach.  I used the Sync Photos function in iTunes to transfer the video file from my PC to my iPhone Photo library.  Then it was readily accessible in iMovie.

1. Connect your iPhone to iTunes and select it.
2. Click the "Photos" tab and check "Sync Photos"
3. At "Copy photos from" select "Choose folder" and specify the folder where your video is located on your computer.
4. Check the "Include videos" box.
5. Click the "Done" button to begin the Sync.

WARNING!

If you already have photos from your computer synced with your iPhone you'll need to be sure your video is in the same folder as the other photos or else the previously synced photos will be deleted from your iPhone.  You'll get multiple warnings from iTunes but it's nothing to worry about as long as all of your synced photos and videos are included in the folder chosen in step #3.